# Adding contact using sync adapter makes sync adapter keep syncing in infinite loop

Tags: android, performance, android-syncadapter

I have implement a sync adapter which sync my contacts with server and return fewer contacts which are registered on my application. I add my app-account to these contacts and add them to my phonebook contact.
I implemented an Observer class which observes if there is any change in my phonebook-contacts(like add,edit or delete) as below

```
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mAccount = CreateSyncAccount(this);
    ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(mAccount, AUTHORITY, true);

    mResolver = getContentResolver();
    mUri = new Uri.Builder()
            .scheme(SCHEME)
            .authority(AUTHORITY)
            .path(TABLE_PATH)
            .build();
    TableObserver observer = new TableObserver();
    mResolver.registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, true, observer);
```

By doing this, sync adapter goes into infinite loop and keeps syncing contacts with server.

I can guess that it may happened because of adding the contact and the observer starts sync-adapter again and again while adding contact using sync adapter.

MyObserver Class's onChange method is like:

```
@Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri changeUri) {
        mResolver.requestSync(mAccount, AUTHORITY, new Bundle());
    }
```

Please help me to solve it out how can I sync contacts only when user manually modify contacts of phonebook, not when the sync-adapter adds the contact.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to register a `ContentObserver` to trigger a sync yourself. If your sync adapter is configured properly, Android will automatically trigger a sync whenever a contact is created, modified or deleted.

Just make sure your sync adapter has set `android:supportsUploading="true"` in the syncadapter xml file.